# Почему требует скобочку

Tags: c++, c, указатели

[Есть код](https://gist.github.com/harish-r/097688ac7f48bcbadfa5):

```
  struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
        int height;
    };

 node* singleRightRotate(node* &t)
    {
        node* u = t->left;
        t->left = u->right;
        u->right = t;
        t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right))+1;
        u->height = max(height(u->left), t->height)+1;
        return u;
    }
```

Я его переписал для себя:

```
struct avlleaf { // структура для представления узлов дерева
    char key[256];                                // Ключ
    unsigned long long int llupar;                // Числовой параметр
    long long int height;                         // Высота
    struct avlleaf* left;                        // Левый ребенок
    struct avlleaf* right;                       // Правый ребенок
};

// Small Left Rotation
struct avlleaf* SLR(struct avlleaf* &tree){
 struct avlleaf* tmp;
 tmp = tree->right;
 tree->right = tmp->left;
 tmp->left = tree;
 tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;
 tmp->height =  MaxLL(Height(tree->right), tree->height)+1 ;
 return tmp;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> [bcc32 Error] File1.c(83): E2293 ) expected

Comment: В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Выделяет строку struct avlleaf* SLR(struct avlleaf* &tree){

Comment: Если это С, то почему там ссылки?

Comment: На каком языке вы пишете? Почему в вопросе об ошибке компиляции нет указания конкретного языка и стоят теги [C] и [C++] одновременно??

Comment: @VTT На  СИ.....

Comment: @AnT На СИ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В С нет ссылок, поэтому такое

```
struct avlleaf* &tree
```

компилятору непонятно в принципе. Он пытается придумать объяснение, что вы хотели, и решает, что, наверное, просто объявить функцию, указав только тип параметра, но не его имя... И просит скобку.

Comment: И как исправить?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы хотите. Может, вам нужен `**tree`. Может, просто `tree`. Понимаете, вопрос-то некорректный. Как с Алисой в Зазеркалье - когда она спрашивает, куда ей идти. А куда нужно прийти? Все равно. Тогда все равно, куда идти. Вы за рулем - вы и сворачивайте, как в том анекдоте...

Comment: посмотрите код по ссылке выше, пожалуйста
Я сам не совсем понимаю, что нужно :(